# Localizing entity framework validation, and customizing validation

Tags: c#

Currently my entity framework 4 models look like:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "UserNumber is a required field.")]
public string UserNumber { get; set; }
```

I need these error messages localized, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Add a resource file to your project with the messages in (Messages.resx) and then add culture versions of it, for example (Messages.sv-SE.resx). If you for example would add a resource string to these file with the key "UserNumberRequired" you would use the following syntax:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Messages),ErrorMessageResourceName="UserNumberRequired")]
public string UserNumber { get; set; }
```

Make sure that you set the code-generation to **public** for the base resource file (Messages.resx)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, and just say I wanted to store the localization myself in a xml file, how could I potentially map it then?